# Microsoft Word 2016: Footnote covering page number

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, page-numbers, footnote

I just encountered a strange formatting issue in Word 2016, a footnote is covering the page number (see below). Any recommendations? I can't

1. Add blank lines at the end of the equation (Word immediately move to the next page)
2. Add a page break (the option is greyed out)

[image: Footnote covering page number]